# Php Twitter Api 1.1 strange array characters at the end

Tags: php, twitter

I'm using https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php as my library for the oAuth etc.

I'm just playing around for now, but, when I try to output for example the array text from the twitter api, it will display strange characters at the end.  I'm not sure if this is on purpose intended as an eol from twitter, but it's driving me crazy, at the end of the output it displays the following characters "5?%?0"

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "mytokensorkeys",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "mytokensorkeys",
    'consumer_key' => "mytokensorkeys",
    'consumer_secret' => "mytokensorkeys"
);

/*
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/blocks/create.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';


$postfields = array(
    'screen_name' => '', 
    'skip_status' => '1'
);


$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
echo $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
             ->setPostfields($postfields)
             ->performRequest();*/

/** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
/** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=#smedigitalforum';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),true);

?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta Content-type: application/json; charset=ISO-8859-1 />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css" />


<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="row">
<?php 

    foreach($response as $key => $value){ 
            foreach($value as $tweet){ 

                print_r($tweet['text']);

            }
    }

?>

</div>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```